# how do i change the password prompt format

Tags: password

When i ssh to ubuntu thru putty using username, it prompts for password.
I want to change the format of the word "password". below is the current format.

Using username "kraj".
kraj@x.x.x.x's password:

I want to change it to

Using username "kraj".
kraj@x.x.x.x's type password:

Is it possible. can somebody guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file using the `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers` command.

Add a line:

```
Defaults passprompt="Using username %u. %u@%h's password:"
```

to it. Save. (Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) And then exit (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

Note the `%u` and `%h` values. They will be replaced with the username and hostname respectively.

UPDATE: So, this won't change the PuTTY password prompt. This will only change your system's password prompt when you use `sudo`.

To change the PuTTY prompt, you'll have to change the prompt in the PuTTY source code.